# Eclipse CDT is not working on macOS Monterey

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt, macos-monterey

After upgrading macOS to 'Monterey' Version 12.0.1, Eclipse CPP (4.21.0,2021-09:R) can not be started anymore with the error message

> The application "Eclipse CPP.app" can't be opened.

MacBook model: 2017, Intel Core i5

oracle-jdk: 17.0.1

Comment: I don't see any reports of problems in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) at the moment. If you Right click on the app and select Open does it give any message?

Comment: it gives me the message above in the quotes "The application "Eclipse CPP.app" can't be opened."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by uninstalling eclipse-cpp and re-installing it.

Comment: Does it keep working after rebooting?

Comment: Yes, it’s working